# Nextjs issue with scrolling to a section or div

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS project I am having an issue when I try to scroll to a section or a div. The issue that I am having is when I click on a link that scrolls to a section it always scrolls pass the section or div and goes to the middle of the area I want it to scroll to. I was hoping that I would scroll to the top of the section

example:  [www.example.com/#second](http://www.example.com/#second)
when doing this it will scroll to the middle where this id is

```
<div>
    <div id="first">
        <p>Hello Everyone</p>
        {/* There will be many other element in this div */}
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <p>How are you ding</p>
        {/* There will be many other element in this div */}
    </div>

    <div id="third">
        <p>I am doing great</p>
        {/* There will be many other element in this div */}
    </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting it to scroll right to the top where the text How are you ding however it will scroll doing to where there will be many other element content is